# Definite aricle or zero article: "Who is going to turn up?" - "(The) friends of mine"

Tags: articles

Let us imagine a situation. I meet up with my friend Mike to discuss the party we are organizing. He asks me, "who else is going to turn up?" I say "friends of mine." So the question is: is it correct to say "friends of mine" or "the friends of mine". However, I did not mention which friends, but the word " mine" specifies which friends. "The friends of mine," not his. Mine. So it is unclear to me should I omit "the" or not.

Comment: "_**some** friends of mine_" (or "_some of my friends_") would be my natural choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural and  straightforward thing to say is

> Some friends of mine

The bare plural *friends of mine* is not the most straightforward/natural   thing to say.

As you've stated, *of mine* designates "which friends" (or "whose friends") they are, so native speakers wouldn't use *the friends of mine* as a first response here. It's not natural.

However, if Mike is not satisfied with the answer *some friends of mine* and asks about these friends in more detail (by asking something like  *Exactly which friends are you talking about?*), then you could respond with *the friends of mine* as part of a response such as

> the friends of mine that always come over

or

> the friends of mine that you've met before

Now *the friends of mine* is okay, in combination with some further identification.

Comment: But how it would be in case the intended meaning is "'all (the) friends' of mine will be there"? 'Some' suggests 'several' but not 'all of them'. I understand that 'the friends of mine' is not idiomatic, but could you explain whether  'the friends of mine' suggests, if not idiomatically, than at least in principle, the meaning 'all my friends (I have ever)'?

Comment: *Some* is, as you've realized, *indefinite* as to amount. *Some* is sometimes called the equivalent of a plural indirect article. However, neither the  bare plural *friends of mine* nor *the friends of mine* must mean *all my friends*. To say explicitly  that you mean *all*,  you need to say *all (of) my friends*. After all, if I go to Austria and take photos of *the mountains* it is unlikely anyone will interpret my statement to mean *all of the mountains (of Austria)*. In short  no, the plural of a count noun does not have the meaning of *all*. @Giorgi

Comment: I have realized. The 'logic' I was following when writing the comment was as follows: when 'the' precedes a plural noun, it 'extracts' a set of specific things; then, in case of _the mountains of Austria_, the mountains that are in Austria not elsewhere are specified. It seems to me that here the connotation of 'all mountains' is present in the sense of 'all of them that are in Austria'; otherwise, some of them would be excluded, seeming unnatural. if I restrict my above question to plural nouns that are preceded by 'the' and modified by 'of' prepositional phrase, would this make a difference?

Answer (score -1):

Actually both are grammatically correct.
But "Friends of mine" is preferred, because  "The friends of mine" is non idiomatic.